# Angular 5 Select Option Frozen after Updating Array

Tags: javascript, angular, drop-down-menu

I have a select dropdown:

```
<select class="form-control" id="teamSelect" [disabled]="!isSubmitButtonDisabled()" [(ngModel)]="selectedTeam" (ngModelChange)="onTeamChange($event)" style="width: 50%;">
  <option *ngFor="let team of teams" [ngValue]="team">{{ team.text }}</option>
</select>
```

I populate it in `ngOnit` like this:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this._microService.getTeams()
        .subscribe(team => {
            this.teams = team.map(m => { return { text: m.name, value: m.name } as Select; });
            this.teams.unshift( { text: '', value: ''} as Select)
        }
        );
}
```

No problems!

Later I have button click that should add a new item to the dropdown...

```
onCreateTeam(team: string = ''): void {
    if(team != '') {
        let t = { text: team, value: team }  as Select;
        this.teams.push(t);
        this.selectedTeam = t;
    }
}
```

The dropdown gets populated but then I can't select anything. Is there a way to update the array in `let team of teams` from my component so the DOM gets the new option, and still allows a selection?

No errors are thrown in the Console.

Comment: **"I can't select anything"** ,Can you elaborate this part on what you are doing and what is happening? Are you able to interact with other elements in the page?

Comment: Also remove `[disabled]="!isSubmitButtonDisabled()"` and try once to see if the `select` is becoming *disabled*.

Comment: wow!  I totally just noticed that... ngShame :)